# Strategy decision according to failed actor

Tags: java, akka

Imagine I have a parent actor with 2 children. 
Its children are different type of actors but both of them can throw the same exception.
 How can I achieve the following behavior: if the exception was thrown by 1 actor I'd like to resume but if it was sent by another one I want to stop it?

Comment: Sounds a bit odd design. Why would you decide on what to do based on who did something rather than what was done?

Comment: There are some common exception thrown (index out of bounds, runtimeexception) but one of them can perfect just ignore and continue working but the other one must stop

Comment: I thought about trapping then and rethrowing with a different exception but it seems a bit tricky.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Perhaps you could include some example code to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to define different supervisor strategies for the children by inserting another layer into your actor hierarchy. That is, instead of the following, where `c1` and `c2` are children of `parent`...

```
 parent
  / \
c1   c2
```

...you could do the following:

```
   parent
    / \
  p1   c2     
  /
c1
```

You can define different supervisor strategies in `parent` and `p1`: the strategy in the former would apply for `c2`, and the strategy in the latter would apply for `c1`.